# Casting in mixed type calculations in C?

Tags: c, casting, types

If I define these variables:

```
double x0, xn, h;
int n;
```

and I have this mathematical expression:

```
h = (xn - x0)/n;
```

Is it necessary that I cast n into double prior doing the division for maximum accuracy like in

```
h = (xn - x0)/ (double) n;
```

I wrote a program to check the above but both expressions give the same answers. I understand that C will promote the integer to double type as variables xn and x0 are of type double but strangely enough in a book, the second expression with casting was emphasized.

My question would be if I'm thinking right.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: The question is "does the cast in the second expression provide any benefit whatsoever?"

Comment: My question would be if I'm thinking right. Sorry for not mentioning this. Thank you all for your helpful comments which has helped to clarify a sticky point for me.

Comment: The operands are always promoted to the highest type if I understand well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, and the book you read is either mistaken or being over-cautious (like people who claim that you should always test `0 == x` instead of `x == 0`). The expression without the cast should always give precisely the same result as the expression with the cast.

Comment: The cast is indeed unnecessary if at least one operand is already a `double`.  However, it's easy to write `double f = 3 / 5`, and be quite surprised when `f` is always zero.  I suspect the recommendation to always cast an integer argument in a floating point expression comes, at last in part, from the usual correct form of this: `double f = (double)3 / 5`.

Comment: Thanks. In your case, we can also write f = 3./5 or f = 3/5. so as to enable floating point calculations.

Answer (score 2):

No, this conversion is unnecessary because the numerator is a `double`. This promotes `n` to a `double` as well. The book probably mentions the explicit cast as a good habit, because if `xn` and `x0` were `int`s then the expression would only use integer division.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is as good as the one that I've accepted but I had to make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's unnecessary in this situation. It's typically needed in situations where you want a result that's different in type from the operands. A typical one is when doing timing. You often end up with code like: `double(end_time-start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` In this case, the cast really is needed, because all the inputs are (typically) integer types, but you want a floating point result.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is as good as the one that I've accepted but I had to make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the precision of any expression is the same as the highest precision constant/variable involved in the expression.

Explicit Casts are useful:

> - **As a precaution**.
>
> Tomorrow you may edit the variables in
>   the expression to use ints. A cast
>   would still return the proper value
>
> - **As a guide**.
>
> Someone else refering/modfiying ur code will easily understand that U are using a **double**.
>
> i.e. "Let Ur code be its own comment !!"